# How To Reposition Elements On Device Rotation In Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, device-orientation

I'm working on an application that should support both portrait and landscape orientations. There is no problem with using auto layout for re arranging the controls in the view but there is something that i cannot do with auto layout. I have two views under each other in the portrait view and i want them to be next to each other in landscape view. I can move the bottom view in the right X position but it is still under the top view. this picture describes what i want to do:

http://www.hesamstore.ir/Orient.png

How Can I Do This?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add constraints to all the IBOutlets.

add Constraints - 1. Height,width, Trailing and leading , and that would solve it,
If you want accurate ratio then select two outlets and add horizontal constraints with a ratio.

And also select a label and its corresponding switch and add horizontal spacing and do it to EQUAL.

Yup that should do it.

Comment: yeah n this is called autolayout, 
Writing codes for frames are obsolete after autolayout came forth in ios6 (i think). :)

Comment: nice solution. but have some questions. i add leading Space To Super View to the 4 first pair of options. they stick to the left. and i add trailing Space To Super View to the 4 second ones. they stick to the right but they are still under the first set o f options. what to do?

Comment: add a complete set of constraints to only 1 label+switch set from either side,
The ones below them, just select the one with all the constraints n the below set and vertical spacing, then follow the same to the ones below them, 
Its like a equation, you got to set it right for 1 and you connect 1 with the right one, and it becomes right, then go on like this, 
But it depends on the layout of your app.

Comment: it was successful but in portrait mode these two sets of options overlap each other. :| . is this a normal thing?

Comment: to the sets of label-switch that has all constraints, add a constraints (if already there then make an edit:) top space to superview (considering the sets are the topmost,) select each one and add/edit these constraints, WITH a RATIO , make a guess of how the ratio should be in portrait vs landscape and set that distance, and a priority of less that trailing space but more than height.

Answer (score 0):

just implements this method to your code...

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

    BOOL isPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);
    if(isPortrait == NO)
    {
        // this is landScape mode....
        // here give the frames that you want for your controls...
    }
    if(isPortrait == YES)
    {
        // this is portrait mode....
        // here give the frames that you want for your controls...
    }

}
```